# Mudar qual "type input" aparece

Tags: jquery, html

Eu tenho um código que faz formulário com perguntas e vários tipos de resposta("text, radio, check-box") e gostaria de um código com `jquery` para colocar no meu html que quando a pessoa selecionar opção texto- mostra o `input type="text"` e esconde o `input type="radio"` e o `input type="checkbox"` e o mesmo com os outros, tipo o Google form.

Segue imagem de como está atualmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o código fonte do que você já fez e remove a imagem.

Comment: Olá Thales. Podes colocar na pergunta o teu HTML?

Comment: Adiciona seu HTML, que fica mais fácil de responder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $("#tipo_input").on("change", function() {
     var tipo = $(this).val();
     $("span[class^='tipo-']:not(.tipo-"+tipo+")").hide();
     $("span[class='tipo-"+tipo+"']").show();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Tipo de campo</label>
<select id="tipo_input">
  <option value=""> Selecione...</option>
  <option value="texto"> Campo de texto</option>
  <option value="radio"> Múltipla escolha</option>
  <option value="check"> Caixas de seleção</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<span class='tipo-texto'>
  <label>Campo texto</label>
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <br>
</span>
<span class='tipo-radio'>
  <label>
    <input type="radio"> Opção radio 1
    <input type="radio"> Opção radio 2
  </label>
  <br>
  <br>
</span>
<span class='tipo-check'>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Opção check
  </label>
</span>
```

Não sei como está seu HTML, mas você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

Veja que existem elementos span com classes "tipo-{tipo_do_input}" envolvendo cada tipo de input, junto com seus labels. Uso essas classes para fazer o seguinte, usando JQuery:

O que o código faz é selecionar os elementos do tipo span que não possuem a classe "tipo-{tipo_selecionado}" (usando o selector :not, veja mais sobre ele [aqui](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)) e os esconde, além de exibir o elemento span com a classe selecionada, caso este tenha sido escondido anteriormente.

Link do exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle: [https://jsfiddle.net/m7dn9Lo4/](https://jsfiddle.net/m7dn9Lo4/3)